# pyomo abstractmodel buld power flow constrict error

Tags: python, pyomo

I am a novice in pyomo modeling, I hope to get your help, thank you, I built the power system scheduling model through pyomo, when I started to build the model, I did not consider the DC power flow constraints, that is, the constraints 1-5 considered, the model runs without problems, it can be solved, but after adding the power flow constraints, the model is not feasible, and the constraints 101-105 can be run, where DModel.xiangjiao represents the phase angle of the node, DModel.zhilu_p represents the transmission power of the branch, DModel.ru_fu is a 0,1 auxiliary variable, Zhejiang makes the transmission power of my path greater than 0, as shown in constraint 103, in constraints 101 and 102, I define the range of phase angles, in 105 and 104 I define the range of the transmission power of the branch, 103 connects the branch of the branch, that is, the branch whose maximum power is not zero, Set his transmission power to the ratio of the difference between the two phase angles and the reactance of the corresponding branch, 1010 constraint is the node power balance, for the node with generator set, I set it to, power generation power + branch inflow power - demand - outflow power = 0, no generator set node, branch inflow power - demand - outflow power = 0, when the csv data reading before the introduction of the 1010 constraint, the model runs and shows that the model is not feasible, I estimate that there may be a conflict in data reading, but the specific reason has not been found, Thank you all for your help

My code looks like this

```
from pyomo.environ import *#容量   启停机
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
from pyomo.environ import value
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition

DModel = AbstractModel()

#多维索引  火 新
DModel.gen = Set()
DModel.rgen = Set()
DModel.t = Set()

DModel.I = Set()
DModel.J = Set()

DModel.diankang = Param(DModel.I,DModel.J)
DModel.zhilu_pmax = Param(DModel.I,DModel.J)
DModel.jiediangonglv = Param(DModel.I)
DModel.a = Param(DModel.J)

#参数设置
DModel.Demand = Param(DModel.t)

DModel.gen_cost_a = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.gen_cost_b = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.gen_cost_c = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.Cap = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.min = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.gen_up = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.down = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.downcost = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.pa = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.pb = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.p_cost = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.sun_cost = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.oil_cost = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.EG_price = Param(DModel.gen)
DModel.EG_node = Param(DModel.gen)

DModel.rgen_cost = Param(DModel.rgen,mutable=True)
DModel.RCap = Param(DModel.rgen,DModel.t)
DModel.w_cost = Param(DModel.rgen)
DModel.kc = Param(DModel.rgen,mutable=True)
DModel.REG_node = Param(DModel.rgen)
DModel.wind_pre = Param(DModel.t)


#变量设置
DModel.state = Var(DModel.gen, DModel.t,within=Binary)
DModel.EG = Var(DModel.gen, DModel.t, within=NonNegativeReals)
DModel.REG = Var(DModel.rgen, DModel.t, domain=NonNegativeReals)
DModel.xiangjiao = Var(DModel.I,DModel.t,within=Reals)
DModel.zhilu_p = Var(DModel.I,DModel.J,DModel.t,within=NonNegativeReals)
DModel.ru_fu = Var(DModel.I,DModel.J,DModel.t,within=Binary)


#目标函数
def obj_expression(DModel):
    expr1 = sum(sum((DModel.gen_cost_a[g] * DModel.EG[g, t]**2+DModel.gen_cost_b[g] * DModel.EG[g, t]+DModel.gen_cost_c[g]) for g in DModel.gen) for t in DModel.t)#火电成本
    expr2 = sum(sum(DModel.rgen_cost[rg] * DModel.REG[rg, t] for rg in DModel.rgen) for t in DModel.t)  # 风电成本
    expr3 = sum(sum(DModel.kc[rg] * (RCap_dict[rg, t] - DModel.REG[rg, t]) for rg in DModel.rgen) for t in DModel.t)#qifengchengfa
    expr4 = sum(sum(DModel.downcost[g] * (1 - DModel.state[g, t - 1]) * DModel.state[g, t] for g in DModel.gen) for t in np.arange(2, 25))#huodian启动成本
    #expr4 = sum(DModel.zhilu_p[I,J,t] for I in DModel.I for J in DModel.J for t in DModel.t )  #sense=minimize
    return expr1+expr2+expr3+expr4
DModel.sysCost = Objective(rule=obj_expression, sense=maximize)
#约束
def limit_101(DModel,I,t):
    return DModel.xiangjiao[I,t] >= -1.57
DModel.limit_101 = Constraint(DModel.I, DModel.t, rule= limit_101)

def limit_102(DModel,I,t):
    return DModel.xiangjiao[I,t] <= 1.57
DModel.limit_102 = Constraint(DModel.I, DModel.t, rule= limit_102)

def limit_103(DModel,I,J,t):
    if DModel.zhilu_pmax[I,J] != 0:
        return DModel.zhilu_p[I, J, t] == (DModel.xiangjiao[I,t] - DModel.xiangjiao[J,t])*DModel.ru_fu[I, J, t] / DModel.diankang[I, J]
    return DModel.zhilu_p[I, J, t] == 0
DModel.limit_103 = Constraint(DModel.I,DModel.J, DModel.t, rule= limit_103)

def limit_104(DModel, I,J,t):
    return DModel.zhilu_p[I, J, t] <= DModel.zhilu_pmax[I, J]
DModel.limit_104 = Constraint(DModel.I,DModel.J, DModel.t, rule= limit_104)

def limit_105(DModel, I,J,t):
    return DModel.zhilu_p[I, J, t] >= 0
DModel.limit_105 = Constraint(DModel.I,DModel.J, DModel.t, rule= limit_105)

gen_dict = {}
with open('generation.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # 跳过第一行（标题行）
    for row in reader:  # 读取每一行数据
        key = row[0]  # 第一列数据作为键值
        value = row[15]  # 第二列数据作为对应的数值
        gen_dict[key] = value # 将键值和对应的数值添加到字典中
rgen_dict = {}
with open('Rgeneration.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # 跳过第一行（标题行）
    for row in reader:  # 读取每一行数据
        key = row[0]  # 第一列数据作为键值
        value = row[4]  # 第二列数据作为对应的数值
        rgen_dict[key] = value  # 将键值和对应的数值添加到字典中
merged_dict = {**gen_dict, **rgen_dict}  #合并字典
merged_keys = [key for key, value in merged_dict.items()]  # 找键
my_list = list(merged_dict.values())
my_list = [int(x) for x in my_list]  # 找数值
def limit_1010(DModel,I,J,t):
    if I in my_list:
        merged_keys = [key for key, value in merged_dict.items() if value == str(I)]
        inflow =  sum(DModel.zhilu_p[J, I, t] for J in DModel.I )
        outflow = sum(DModel.zhilu_p[I, J, t] for J in DModel.J )
        return sum(DModel.EG[gen, t] for gen in DModel.gen if gen in merged_keys) + sum(DModel.REG[rgen, t] for rgen in DModel.rgen if rgen in merged_keys) +\
                inflow-outflow-DModel.Demand[t] * DModel.jiediangonglv[I]== 0
    return sum(DModel.zhilu_p[J, I, t] for J in DModel.I ) - sum(DModel.zhilu_p[I, J, t] for J in DModel.J )-DModel.Demand[t] * DModel.jiediangonglv[I] == 0
DModel.limit_1010 = Constraint(DModel.I,DModel.J, DModel.t, rule= limit_1010)

def limit_109(DModel,I,t):
    return DModel.xiangjiao[2,t] == 0
DModel.limit_109 = Constraint(DModel.I, DModel.t, rule= limit_109)

# 1 供求约束      旋转备用
def limit_1(DModel, t):
    return sum(DModel.EG[g,t] for g in DModel.gen) + \
        sum(DModel.REG[g,t] for g in DModel.rgen) == DModel.Demand[t]
DModel.limit_1 = Constraint(DModel.t, rule=limit_1)

def limit_1_1(DModel, t):#上
    return sum((DModel.Cap[g]-DModel.EG[g,t])*DModel.state[g, t] for g in DModel.gen) >= 0.05*DModel.Demand[t]
DModel.limit_1_1 = Constraint(DModel.t, rule=limit_1_1)

def limit_1_2(DModel, t):#下
    return sum((DModel.EG[g,t]-DModel.min[g])*DModel.state[g, t] for g in DModel.gen)>= 0.05*DModel.Demand[t]
DModel.limit_1_2 = Constraint(DModel.t, rule=limit_1_2)
#2火电出力上下限约束
def limit_21(DModel, gen, t):
    return DModel.EG[gen,t]<=DModel.Cap[gen]*DModel.state[gen, t]
DModel.limit_21 = Constraint(DModel.gen, DModel.t, rule=limit_21)
def limit_22(DModel, gen, t):
    return DModel.min[gen] * DModel.state[gen, t]<=DModel.EG[gen, t]
DModel.limit_22 = Constraint(DModel.gen, DModel.t, rule=limit_22)
# #3火电爬坡约束
def limit_31(DModel, gen, t):
    if t == DModel.t.first():
        return Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return (DModel.EG[gen, t] - DModel.EG[gen, t - 1])*DModel.state[gen, t] <= DModel.gen_up[gen]
DModel.limit_31 = Constraint(DModel.gen, DModel.t, rule=limit_31)

def limit_32(DModel, gen, t):
    if t == DModel.t.first():
        return Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return DModel.EG[gen, t-1] - DModel.EG[gen, t]*DModel.state[gen, t] <= DModel.gen_up[gen]
DModel.limit_32 = Constraint(DModel.gen, DModel.t, rule=limit_32)
#  4火电启停机约束
def limit_41(DModel, gen, t): #  停机
    if t == DModel.t.first():
        return Constraint.Skip
    if t+DModel.down[gen]>=24:
        return DModel.state[gen, t]== DModel.state[gen, 24-DModel.down[gen]]
    return sum((1-DModel.state[gen, t]) for t in range(t,t+DModel.down[gen]))>=DModel.down[gen]*(DModel.state[gen, t-1]-DModel.state[gen, t])
DModel.limit_41 = Constraint(DModel.gen, DModel.t, rule=limit_41)

def limit_42(DModel, gen, t):#开机
    if t == DModel.t.first():
        return Constraint.Skip
    if t+DModel.down[gen]>=len(DModel.t):
        return DModel.state[gen, t]== DModel.state[gen, 24-DModel.down[gen]]
    return sum(DModel.state[gen, t] for t in range(t,t+DModel.down[gen]))>=DModel.down[gen]*(DModel.state[gen, t]-DModel.state[gen, t-1])
DModel.limit_42 = Constraint(DModel.gen, DModel.t, rule=limit_42)

#5风电出力
def limit_51(DModel,rgen,t):
    return DModel.REG[rgen,t]<=RCap_dict[rgen,t]
DModel.limit_51 = Constraint(DModel.rgen, DModel.t, rule= limit_51)


#数据读取
data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='load.csv', format='set', set='t', model=DModel)
data.load(filename='load.csv', index='t', param=['Demand','wind_pre'] , model=DModel)
data.load(filename='generation.csv', format='set', set='gen', model=DModel)
data.load(filename='generation.csv',index='gen', param=['Cap','min','gen_cost_a','gen_up','down','gen_cost_b','gen_cost_c','pa','pb','p_cost','sun_cost','oil_cost','EG_price','downcost','EG_node'], model=DModel)
data.load(filename='Rgeneration.csv', format='set', set='rgen', model=DModel)
data.load(filename='Rgeneration.csv', index='rgen',param=['rgen_cost','w_cost','kc','REG_node'], model=DModel)
RCap_dict = pd.read_csv('reneable_load.csv',index_col='t').unstack(0).to_dict()

data.load(filename='jiedian.csv', format='set', set='I', model=DModel)
data.load(filename='jiedian.csv', index='I', param=['jiediangonglv'], model=DModel)
data.load(filename='jiedian.csv', format='set', set='J', model=DModel)
data.load(filename='jiedian.csv', index='J', param=['a'], model=DModel)
data.load(filename="zhiludiankang.csv",param='diankang',format='array')
data.load(filename="zhilugonglv.csv",param='zhilu_pmax',format='array')



instance = DModel.create_instance(data)
opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')#cplex_direct
opt.options['NonConvex'] = 2
#opt.options['mipgap'] = 0.01#求解精度
results = opt.solve(instance,symbolic_solver_labels=True,tee=True)
instance.solutions.load_from(results)
# instance.pprint()
filename = "流入流出.lp"
instance.write(filename,io_options={'symbolic_solver_labels': True})
```